# Error handling in Angular2 interceptor

Tags: angular

I am trying to write a simple http interceptor for my Angular4 app to handle basic things like turning loading spinner on off, a little logging perhaps and, at some point, caching.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoadingOverlayService } from '../../../services/loadingoverlay/loadingoverlay.service';
import { MdSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class MainInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
request: HttpRequest<any>;

constructor(public loadingOverlay: LoadingOverlayService, public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {

}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.request = req;
    let options = this._dealwithOptions();

    if (!options.disableOverlay)
        this.loadingOverlay.sync(true);

    const started = Date.now();
    return next.handle(this.request)
        .do(event => {
            console.log(event);
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log(HttpResponse);
                const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
                console.log(`Request for ${req.urlWithParams} took ${elapsed} ms.`);

                if (!options.disableOverlay)
                    this.loadingOverlay.sync(false);
            }
        });
}

_dealwithOptions() {
    let rtrn: any = {};

    var options = this.request.headers.get('requestoptions');
    if (options != null) {
        rtrn = JSON.parse(options);
        this.request = this.request.clone({ headers: this.request.headers.delete('requestoptions') });
    }

    return (rtrn);
}
}
```

`LoadingOverlayService` is my own service to pass the overlay on or off message to the component that has overlay HTML.

Everything works fine UNTIL there is an error coming from the server. How do capture, read, and pass along error event in the interceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second input parameter of `.do()` is `errorHandler`, see https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md